# debug scrapy with vs2017

Tags: scrapy, visual-studio-2017

I'm not good at English to express, Sorry.

I want to know how to debug scrapy with vs2017.

I work well with vs2015,here is the way:

```
import os    
os.system("run.cmd")
```

and run.cmd:

```
scrapy crawl weiqn --nolog    
pause
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Haha,now I found the way.
It is the same as Pycharm debugger.
Hear is pycharm:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnF7g.jpg)